# Validación de $apply y $digest en AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Estoy dando soporte a un código hecho en **AngularJS** para realizar unas modificaciones que me han solicitado, y me encontré con el siguiente código.

```
$scope.open($event, item){
    if ($scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && $scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest') {
       // Lógica del sistema
    } else {
       $timeout(function() {
           $scope.open($event, item);
       }, 10);
    }
}
```

Este tema de `$apply` y `$digest` no lo he entendido del todo bien y me genera la duda de ¿que está validando esa condición? ¿por que en el `else` se utiliza un `setTimeout` para volver a ejecutar la misma función? Cabe aclarar que la función es ejecutada por medio de un `ng-click` común y corriente.

Tratando de entender un poco más el código cambié la condición a la siguiente forma y funciona igual.

```
$scope.open($event, item){
    if ($scope.$$phase == null) {
       // Lógica del sistema
    } else {
       $timeout(function() {
           $scope.open($event, item);
       }, 10);
    }
}
```

¿Que implicaciones tiene usar la condición 1 o la condición 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El `$scope` tiene un método llamado [`$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) que sirve para cuando actualizas valores fuera del entorno de Angular este se entere de que ha ocurrido un cambio y ejecute un nuevo ciclo [digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest).

> Procesa todos los watchers del scope actual y sus hijos. Debido a que un litener de un watch puede cambiar el modelo el $digest() se continua llamando hasta que no se disparen más listeners. Esto significa que es posible llegar a un ciclo infinito. Esta función arrojará el error `'Maximum iteration limit exceeded.'` si el número de iteraciones sobrepasa las 10.

El problema es que si ejecutas este método y en ese instante está ocurriendo un ciclo te genera el siguiente error

> Error: $apply already in progress

Así que te ves obligado a verificar esta propiedad para no tener el error.

Tu código verifica esta condición y ejecuta la lógica sólo cuando el modelo está estable. De lo contrario programa una verificación de manera recursiva en los próximos 10 milisegundos hasta que sea posible actualizar los valores.

```
$timeout(function() {
     $scope.open($event, item);
 }, 10);
```

Ten en cuenta que estas propiedades son privadas, por eso están señaladas con `$$` y no con el habitual `$` y tampoco se encuentran [documentadas](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) lo que te da a entender que debes utilizar estas técnicas sólo cuando lo necesites y no de manera indiscriminada.